# Sentence Case function not recognize all characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text area where the user can type some text, and after that, with function, i transform it to sentence case. The first letter is capitalized, as is the dot that follows it.

##### Example

input --> output

hello, one two. three four --> Hello, one two. Three four

But it works only with regular letters from `a` to `z`. But I also require characters from other languages, such as Danish `Æ, Ø, Å`

here is functions which wors great with letters from `a` to `z`

```
    function sentenceCase(input, lowercaseBefore) {
        input = (input === undefined || input === null) ? '' : input;
        if (lowercaseBefore) { input = input.toLowerCase(); }
        return input.toString().replace(/(^|\. *)([a-z])/g, function (match, separator, char) {
            return separator + char.toUpperCase();
        });
    }
```

I found that there is something like this to catch another characters also `[\p{L}\p{M}]`
it works in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) `(^|\. *)([\p{L}\p{M}])` but when I put it in the code, the function not showing any errors and also not working. Text is not transforming.

replace `[a-z]` with `[\p{L}\p{M}]`

Comment: `\p{X}` classes only work with `u` flag in ECMAScript 2018+ compliant engines. `/(^|\. *)(\p{Ll})/gu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any Unicode lowercase letters, you need to use `\p{Ll}` Unicode category/property class together with the **`u` flag**:

```js
/(^|\. *)(\p{Ll})/gu
```

Now, this will match multiple occurrences of

- `(^|\. *)` - Group 1: start of string or a `.` followed with zero or more regular spaces
- `(\p{Ll})` - Group 2: any Unicode lowercase letter.